# Using an object as a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a question related to the use of an express application object (app object) as a callback function. From what I know, an express application is an object that has methods and properties to help in the routing of HTTP requests. To use the app object with an HTTP server, we use it as a callback FUNCTION for this server:

```
var app = express();
// ...
var server = http.createServer(app);
```

The same thing goes for a Router object :

```
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
// ...
app.use('/', router);
```

I was wondering how an object can be considered as a function. It's true that a function inherits from the Object class, but from what I know it doesn't have methods and properties like it is supposed to be in an express application.

Comment: Every function in JavaScript is a Function object! In JavaScript, functions are first-class objects, because they can have properties and methods just like any other object. What distinguishes them from other objects is that functions can be called. In brief, they are Function objects.

Comment: It seems like part of your confusion is that `app` actually _is_ a function. It's not just a plain object that they're somehow treating as a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Javascript object hierarchy, a function is a type of object.  Not only can a function be called, but it can also have properties just like a plain object.  You can think of it like the function object inherits from the plain object.

So, in the case of `express` in your example, it is a function and it also has properties.

So, you can call it directly:

```
var app = express();
```

And, you can access its properties:

```
var router = express.Router();
```

You can do this with your own functions:

```
function myFunc() {
   console.log("hello");
}

myFunc();    // outputs "hello"

myFunc.greeting = "goodbye";

console.log(myFunc.greeting);   // outputs "goodbye"
```

And, you could even combine them like this:

```
function myFunc() {
   console.log(myFunc.greeting);
}

myFunc.greeting = "goodbye";

myFunc();    // outputs "goodbye"
```

---

Note, the Express library did not have to design it the way they did.  They could have exported a plain object with multiple properties where one of the properties on that plain object was the express function and made it work like this:

```
const expressLib = require('express');
const app = expressLib.Express();

const server = http.createServer(app);

const router = expressLib.Router();
app.use('/', router);
```

So, it was simply an API design choice to make the `express` function the main export and put properties on that function rather than export a plain object that has all the properties on it, including the express function.

Comment: Anyone care to explain why the downvote?  I'm happy to improve the answer if necessary.